# Possible to pass format specifier for an argument as another argument to String.Format?

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

For instance, let's say I have the DateTime format-string in a string variable, is there any syntax or method in .NET that would let me do the equivalent of this invalid code:

```
String line = String.Format("{0:{1}}", DateTime.Now, dateTimeFormat);
                                ^^^                        ^
                                 |                         |
                                 +-- this would use this --+
```

Comment: easy solution is using DateTime.Now.Day/Minute etc. But that won't be a generic solution...

Comment: There's plenty of easy solutions, for instance I could just format the DateTime to a string as the argument, ie. String.Format("{0}", DateTime.ToString(dateTimeFormat)), I was just hoping there was something built in :)

Comment: If we're going with old school easy solutions (i would have definitely written something like this back in school :)

String line = String.Format("{0:"+dateTimeFormat+"}", DateTime.Now);

:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this syntax overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) pretty much excludes dynamic parameters.

You will have to use a 2 stage system somehow, either pre-formatting your Date or by generating a format string. But I think both will be worse than the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just

```
string line = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateTimeFormat);
```

?

Comment: Nothing, I was just asking if I *could* do it.